# How to Validation a Guid type in Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a property in My model like this:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a user!!!")]
 public Guid UserId { get; set; }
```

in MVC View i have

```
<td>*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId) :</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("UserId", "--Select--")</td>
```

in my html source i have:

```
<select id="UserId" name="UserId">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="30afa71d-6983-410a-bb68-26fd2438b969">User A</option>
<option value="b1d81277-72bc-4aa6-8fc4-524cd01d47a4">User B</option>

</select>
```

How can i validate this property that User select a user

Answer (score 8):

You could add a custom `RequiredGuidAttribute`, based on `ValidationAttribute`, that doesnt allow the Empty Guid value:

```
public class RequiredGuidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public RequiredGuidAttribute() => ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.";

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
        => value != null && value is Guid && !Guid.Empty.Equals(value);
}
```

Then on your model you can declare your property as a Guid and decorate as follows:

```
    [RequiredGuid]
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
```

My ASP.NET Core WebApi then returns the following in Postman, when I omit MessageId from the Request Body:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "MessageId": [
            "MessageId is required."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "0HLQ5JBI08329:00000009"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that a none-nullable GUID will always have the default value of Guid.Empty - which is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` - so your required validator never sees the value as empty, or null.

The solution is to make the UserId property nullable:

`public Guid? UserId { get; set; }` (notice the `?` after the property type)

or if you don't want to use the `?` shorthand:

`public Nullable<Guid> UserId { get; set; }`

So your property with its attribute would look like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a user!!!")]
public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RegularExpression` validation attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a user!!!")]
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: How will that help?  The data type is already a Guid.  The compiler will not let you put "Hello, World!" in there.  I think the OP wants to validate that the GUID belongs to a list of valid GUIDs.

Comment: @EricJ. That's a good point.  mtaboy, do you have a specific list of valid `Guid`s?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 8 Preview 2 you can set the `DisallowAllDefaultValues` to true in the `RequiredAttribute` attribute class.

> The RequiredAttribute now allows validating that structs do not equal their default values.

```cs
[Required(DisallowAllDefaultValues = true)]
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
```

For more info: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-preview-2/#requiredattribute-disallowalldefaultvalues.